# Access DataGrid Cell in CodeBehind File WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to access Datagrid cell value in wpf while iterating through all its row.I want to get value of first column of every row.I have tried so many things but couldn't succeed.Please help

**Here is what I am trying**

```
 var dg = productFilterResult.ProductsGrid;
                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    var cellContent = dg.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row);
                    var x = (ContentPresenter)cellContent;
                    var y = x.Content;
                }
```

**This is my xaml file:**

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Id" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Index"  Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="IndexCell" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={StaticResource RowToIndexConvertor}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update" Width="Auto" MinWidth="200" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image  x:Name="EditImg" Style="{DynamicResource EditImg}" Source="/CPOSApplication;component/Icons/edit.png" Tag="{Binding}" MouseDown="Edit_Click"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image  x:Name="DeleteImg" Style="{DynamicResource DeleteImg}" Source="/CPOSApplication;component/Icons/delete.png" Tag="{Binding}" MouseDown="Delete_Click"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code.

```
 public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

            if (presenter == null)
            {
                grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
                presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
            }

            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

Reference link http://svgvijay.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-get-datagrid-cell-in-wpf.html

Comment: I need the value of cell.This gives me DatagridCell

Comment: It gives me null when I try to access its content

Answer (score 2):

This is how it worked for me

```
 var dg = productFilterResult.ProductsGrid;
                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    var cellContent = dg.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row);
                    var cellContentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)cellContent;
                    DataTemplate editingTemplate = cellContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                    TextBlock CellTextBox = editingTemplate.FindName("IndexCell", cellContentPresenter) as TextBlock;
                    string CellValue = CellTextBox.Text;
                    var BindedModel = cellContentPresenter.Content;
                }
```